# Parsing nested XML File as node set

Tags: java, xml, xslt, nested, apache-fop

I have a problem. I have an xml file as below :

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<msrsw>
  <software>
  <chapter>
     <name> Hello world</sample>
     <xref type="xml">C:\ABC\NestedXML.xml</xref>
  </chapter>
  </software>
</msrsw>
```

NestedXml.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <msrsw>
  <software>
  <chapter>
     <name> Nested XML </sample>        
     <age>14</age>
     <country>Canada</country>
  </chapter>
</software>
</msrsw>
```

I am using Apache FOP to produce PDF document (Using Java). FOP needs src and dest params. Src being Main.xml.
My XSLT is as below:

```
<xsl:param name="xmlFileName" />
<xsl:param name="XMLFile" select="document($xmlFileName)"/> 
<xsl:template name="Chapters_1_2_Template">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$XMLFile/*" mode="chapter" />
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="chapter">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:if test="current()[name() = 'xref']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[name() = 'xref']" mode="x" />
        </xsl:if>
     <xsl:if test="current()[name() = 'name']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[name() = 'name']" mode="name" />
        </xsl:if>
     <xsl:if test="current()[name() = 'age']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[name() = 'age']" mode="age" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name" mode="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="age" mode="age">
    <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="country" mode="country">
    <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref" mode="x">
    <xsl:param name="XMLFile" select="document(current())"/> 
    <xsl:call-template name="Chapters_1_2_Template" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

When I execute the above code, i get the following error in the line `<xsl:apply-templates select="$XMLFile/*" mode="chapter" />`:

```
Invalid token XMLFile.
```

When I remove $XMLFile - `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="chapter" />` , it works fine for me with Main.xml file's content.
When I just display the value of current() in xref template, it is parses the NestedXml.xml file and displayes string values in PDF.

**Expected Output is:**

```
Hello world

Nested XML

14

Canada
```

My requirement is to embed the node-set of NestedXML.xml within the`<xref></xref>` tags and recursively applyTemplates on that node-set. 
But the document() function gives me the parsed String content of NestedXml.xml.

I do not want to use the document() function and just get the String value of NestedXml.xml. I need to parse all the tags of NestedXml.xml using the same XSLT.
Please suggest me where am I going wrong. Is this approach right? Is there any other way to do this? 
Or it is not possible to do in this way using XSLT and that XSLT allows including only the parsed String values?

Comment: Can you edit your question with `NestedXML.xml`'s content and post your expected output. Also, the `Main.xml`'s content you've posted is not a valid XML, please correct it.

Comment: I hope it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is that you want just some text nodes, the stylesheet needn't be that complex. Try this simpler stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="msrsw/software/chapter/name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(msrsw/software/chapter/xref)/*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think my question is not still clear. I have 2 xml files here. Main.xml on which this xslt is running. When NestedXml.xml is encountered in Main.xml, xslt should fetch the nodes of NestedXml.xml and start parsing the nodes of NestedXml.xml. Both files will have same type of nodes. It should be like -- startParsingXML() { if xref, fetch path and startParsingXml() }. MSRSW tag can have any tag dynamically. What I have shown is a very small sample. In real, my xml is very huge.